# Error when opening some gdb files with fiona and geopandas

Tags: python, gis, geopandas, fiona

I am trying to open [NYC LION Geodatabase](https://www1.nyc.gov/site/planning/data-maps/open-data/bytes-archive.page?sorts[year]=0) files for 2010, 2011, and 2012.

I successfully opened the 2012 and 2011 geodatabases with geopandas, but I was unable to open the 2010 version.

I've tried using fiona directly, but I kept getting a similar error.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import sys
import requests
from zipfile import ZipFile as zzip
import fiona
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath('..'))

path = r"https://www1.nyc.gov/assets/planning/download/zip/data-maps/open-data/nyc_lion10aav.zip"
r = requests.get(path)
    # open method to open a file on your system and write the contents
    with open("../input_data/nyc_lion10aav.zip", "wb") as file:
        file.write(r.content)
    # opening the zip file in READ mode 
    with zzip("../input_data/nyc_lion10aav.zip", 'r') as file: 
        # printing all the contents of the zip file 
        #file.printdir() 
        path = "../input_data/nyc_lion10aav"
        os.mkdir(path)
        # extracting all the files 
        #rint('Extracting all the files now...') 
        file.extractall(path) 
        print('Done!')

fp = r"../input_data/nyc_lion10aav/lion/lion.gdb"
lion_gdf = gpd.read_file(fp, driver='OpenFileGDB', layer='lion')

fp = r"../input_data/nyc_lion10aav/lion/lion.gdb"
file = fiona.open(fp, driver='OpenFileGDB', layer='lion')
```

[Notebook](https://github.com/jeremysze/GIS_exploration/blob/master/code/GBD_Error.ipynb)

I expected it to go through like the geodatabases from 2011 and 2012 when I ran it in the notebook. I've been searching here and on fiona's github issues to see if others have a similar problem and if there was a solution. But I am fairly new to using these libraries so I don't really understand the traceback in order to figure out what went wrong.

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CPLE_OpenFailedError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
fiona/_shim.pyx in fiona._shim.gdal_open_vector()

fiona/_err.pyx in fiona._err.exc_wrap_pointer()

CPLE_OpenFailedError: ../input_data/nyc_lion10aav/lion/lion.gdb: Permission denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

DriverError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-f49f8c92c671> in <module>
      1 fp = r"../input_data/nyc_lion10aav/lion/lion.gdb"
----> 2 lion_gdf = gpd.read_file(fp, driver='OpenFileGDB', layer='lion')

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\geo\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py in read_file(filename, bbox, **kwargs)
     75 
     76     with fiona_env():
---> 77         with reader(path_or_bytes, **kwargs) as features:
     78 
     79             # In a future Fiona release the crs attribute of features will

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\geo\lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    394     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    395         if local._env:
--> 396             return f(*args, **kwargs)
    397         else:
    398             if isinstance(args[0], str):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\geo\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py in open(fp, mode, driver, schema, crs, encoding, layer, vfs, enabled_drivers, crs_wkt, **kwargs)
    251         if mode in ('a', 'r'):
    252             c = Collection(path, mode, driver=driver, encoding=encoding,
--> 253                            layer=layer, enabled_drivers=enabled_drivers, **kwargs)
    254         elif mode == 'w':
    255             if schema:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\geo\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py in __init__(self, path, mode, driver, schema, crs, encoding, layer, vsi, archive, enabled_drivers, crs_wkt, ignore_fields, ignore_geometry, **kwargs)
    157             if self.mode == 'r':
    158                 self.session = Session()
--> 159                 self.session.start(self, **kwargs)
    160             elif self.mode in ('a', 'w'):
    161                 self.session = WritingSession()

fiona/ogrext.pyx in fiona.ogrext.Session.start()

fiona/_shim.pyx in fiona._shim.gdal_open_vector()

DriverError: ../input_data/nyc_lion10aav/lion/lion.gdb: Permission denied
```